# are intersections of kernels also kernels?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $S,T$ are two linear transformations between some fixed pair $V, V'$ of finite-dimensional real linear vector spaces. Now suppose further that $S,T$ have nontrivial kernels in $V$ and that the intersection of these kernels is, say, nontrivial.

Question: what is a canonical choice of linear transformation $R=R(S,T):V \to V'$ such that $R$ has kernel exactly equal to the intersection of the kernels of $S,T$?

Remark: as application consider the question of determining whether a collection $\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots$ of primitive $k$-vectors in $\wedge ^k \mathbb{R}^{n}$ are formed by wedges of a spanning set for $\mathbb{R}^n$. That is, do the factors of $\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots$ span $\mathbb{R}^n$? Recall that to each element $\zeta \in \wedge^k \mathbb{R}^n$ one can assign the linear transformation $D_\zeta: \mathbb{R}^n \to \wedge^{k+1} \mathbb{R}^n $ which takes $v \mapsto \zeta \wedge v$. Then if $\zeta$ is primitive, one finds $ker D_\zeta$ coincides with the $\mathbb{R}^n$-subspace spanned by the factors of $\zeta$. Explicitly, if $\zeta=v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k$, then $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k \}$ span $ker D_\zeta$.

Our motivation: An answer to the above question should provide a coordinate-free criterion for whether the factors of a collection of primitive $n$-vectors $\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots $ span $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Comment: Not research level, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: expanded and clarified the question.

Comment: If $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ is the basis of the intersection of the kernels of $S$ and $T$, which is known, one can find $R$ as a solution of the linear system $R e_i = 0$, $i = 1, \ldots, n$.

Comment: I don't know of any canonical way to do this. If you allow the range to be changed, then $(S, T): V \rightarrow V' \oplus V'$ works.

Comment: @Stanislav: no good since any such $R$ is not canonical, ie. you still have to extend. Actually, one maybe cannot expect to do better than this: take the pullback of $S,T$ to obtain a subspace $P$ of $V \times V$ and a linear map $R_o: P \to V'$. Take $R$ to be the restriction of $R_o$ along the diagonal $\Delta \subset V \times V$. Then the kernel of $R$ is exactly the intersection $ker S \cap ker T$. This is canonical, but totally worthless. 

Comment: @yang: sure, IF.  

Comment: If you assume that the target space $V'$ is always the same, then $R$ may fail to exist, because $\dim V'$ may be too small. If you allow a different target space, just take a direct product $S\times T:V\toV'\times V'$.

Comment: @Ivanov: I erred in not emphasized my main motivation. In the case of linear maps $\mathbb{R}^{2n} \to \wedge^{n+1}\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ there is no issue of `small' dimension, and a reasonable answer may be possible. 

Comment: Among those who have voted to close, any further comments on why or how to improve the question?

Comment: "Not research level" is different than "elementary". This question (phrased in terms of elementary linear algebra) is non-standard, not to be found in any textbook, and even more importantly: still unanswered! The point of the question, ie. its entire substance, is not to take a different target space. In my opinion, this question has more substance and more significance than half of the daily MO posts. At bottom, almost every problem is a problem in linear algebra. And when we find an honest unanswered linear algebra question, we should appreciate its relevance. 

Comment: Mr. Martel, I recommend you find the books by Greub on linear algebra and multilinear algebra, I believe those are separate volumes. Greub maintained a steady interest in coordinate free presentation, at the price of length of presentation.  I have little interest in this myself. However, I am definitely against questions where someone, asking for help, then repeatedly says No, that one's not right. As you have such a clear idea of what you want, work on this for a few weeks, order some books on interlibrary loan. When you know something for real, ask again.  

Comment: I voted to close, which is inconsistent with my attempt at an answer.  But I do not see how to retract my vote. 

Comment: @Goldstern, I wouldn't worry about it. From what I can see there are two correct answers now. If the question is closed, no additional answers may be added, but you will be able to edit your own answer and, from your reputation points, the question. Both answers give consideration to what "canonical" should mean in this problem. That ought to suffice.

Comment: While I sympathise a little with the OP's frustration, I find the claims "This question (phrased in terms of elementary linear algebra) is non-standard, not to be found in any textbook...In my opinion, this question has more substance and more significance than half of the daily MO posts. At bottom, almost every problem is a problem in linear algebra. And when we find an honest unanswered linear algebra question, we should appreciate its relevance" somewhat overdone. Note that this is "English-speak", so those of you who know how to decode may get some impression of what I *actually* think... 

Comment: I take Qiaochu's definitive answer as evidence that this was in fact a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: But it also doesn't seem to be the question the OP meant to ask, which is really a question about the exterior algebra of a single vector space rather than linear maps between two vector spaces; in that setting there are more natural maps (I think they are essentially generated by wedge products). 

Comment: "When you know something for real, ask again"--okay, I like that advice. 

Answer (score 5):

There is no such choice, if by "canonical" you mean natural in the category-theoretic sense. I am going to rename $V'$ to $W$.

You want to find a natural map $\text{Hom}(V \oplus V, W) \to \text{Hom}(V, W)$ with certain properties. Fixing $V$ and using only naturality in $W$, it follows by the Yoneda lemma that this is equivalent to finding a map $V \to V \oplus V$ and then applying $\text{Hom}(-, W)$. This is equivalent to specifying two maps $f, g : V \to V$ and considering the map $v \mapsto f(v) \oplus g(v)$.

The only maps $V \to V$ which are natural in $V$ are given by scalar multiplication; this is a corollary of the fact that the center of $\text{GL}(V)$ is given by scalars, but this only uses naturality with respect to automorphisms and the proof is easier and more general if you make more thorough use of naturality (see [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/centers-2-categories-and-the-eckmann-hilton-argument/)).

Anyway, the upshot is that the only natural maps from pairs of linear transformations $V \to W$ to linear transformations $V \to W$ are given by taking linear combinations; in other words, all you can do is take

$$(R, S) \mapsto a R + b S$$

for some fixed scalars $a, b$. It's not hard to show that no such choice does what you want (clearly both $a$ and $b$ must be nonzero and then you can take $S = - \frac{a}{b} R$).

Comment: This doesn't directly address the motivational question, but I admit that I don't really understand the relationship between the asked question and the motivational question. Doesn't the motivational question involve thinking about sums of kernels, not intersections? 

Comment: I don't understand how you're argument could rule out the following possibility: suppose $V=W$ has finite dimension. Then $End(V)$ is a ring. Why could we not expect that there exists a polynomial $R$ in two variables over $End(V)$ with the following `mystical' powers: given any two endomorphisms $S,T$ of $V$ the polynomial $R(S,T)$ has kernel exactly equal to the intersections of the kernels of $S,T$, or equal to the sum of the kernels of $S,T$? Does your argument really annihalate this possibility? I would think that the yield $R(S,T)$ should qualify as `canonical'.  

Comment: @J. Martel: it doesn't rule out that possibility. I explicitly use functoriality with respect to $V$ and $W$ separately. 

Comment: @J. Martel: if you want to ask a question which only involves one vector space rather than two, you should probably ask it as a new question (and also clarify the relationship to your motivation, which I still don't really understand). 

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer to your general question:  If you assume that "canonical" means in particular that $f \circ R(S,T) = R(f\circ S, f\circ T)$ whenever $f:V'\to V''$ is 1-1 linear, then there is no canonical solution.

Proof:  If $S$ and $T$ map onto the same $k$-dimensional space $W$, but $R(S,T)$ has to have larger range, then $f$ can be defined quite arbitrarily outside $W$, without influencing $f\circ R$, $f\circ S$.